# Mongoose $maxDistance not precise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation

I am storing places in a Mongoose model (name + coords as [lng, lat]) and have a 2d index on it.

I want to get the nearest locations from a point (lng, lat) within a radius in km.

For this, I use mongoose's $near and $maxDistance parameters.
The issue I am facing is that the radius does not seem to be precise, thus I get wrong results.

Here is my code for the geo search:

```
LocationModel.find({
        loc: {
            $near: coords,
            $maxDistance: max_distance
        }
    }).exec(function(err, locations)
    {
        if(err)
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });

        res.json(locations);
    });
```

I have two locations for my tests:

> Place 1 : 6.614090000000033, 45.4203
>
> Place 2 : 6.905578500000047, 45.4683226
>
> Total distance : 23.36km

The max_distance for $maxDistance is calculated this way:

```
var max_distance = req.params.max_distance / 111.12;
```

When I provide the reference point as Place A, I only get results when I set the max_distance to 33km and over, and not 24km as it should be.

Can someone explain me what is wrong here? Maybe the 111.12 (which I found all over the Internet), or is it something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since you are talking about geolocations, I'd suggest these changes:

1. Use `2dsphere` index instead of `2d`. This will ensure the search takes into consideration that the earth is not a 2d plane.
2. Change your model to represent the coordinates in the GeoJSON format.

So your schema should look something like this:

```
    var LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      location: {
        type: {
           type: String,
           default: "Point"
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number]
        }
      }
    });
    LocationSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
```

Now you can use [Model.geoNear](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.geoNear) to perform your query. To get your distance in kilometers, you need to use the `distanceMultiplier` option with the radius of earth in kilometers as the value. Don't forget the `{ spherical: true }` flag.

Note: I've used it as part of an aggregation and its pretty accurate. It should work the same in the above case also. Mongoose documentation doesn't talk about it. Use [this from MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#dbcmd.geoNear)

Answer (score 1):

1 degree is aprox 111 kms at equator, where your 111.12 comes from. But as we move away from the equator it becomes less due to the convergence of the meridians(longitude) as we approach the pole.

```
Degree  Lat         Lng
0°      110.574 km  111.320 km
15°     110.649 km  107.551 km
30°     110.852 km  96.486 km
45°     111.132 km  78.847 km
60°     111.412 km  55.800 km
75°     111.618 km  28.902 km
90°     111.694 km  0.000 km
```

You could use [**equirectangular approximation**](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) for this.

```
x = Δlat * cos (Δlng/2)
y = ΔLng
d = R ⋅ √x² + y²
where Δlat & Δlng in radians & R = radius of earth
Δlat is the difference between the 2 lats  & Δlng that of lats
```

Comment: When I use this table (i.e.: divide my max_distance to the computed Lng), I find the correct values.
But I can't find how to calculate this value. Can you help me on this and give me the formula?

Every website I went to propose formulas with two lat / long (as your formula does with Δlat & Δlng) but I only have one.

Comment: Δlat  is the difference between the 2 lats & Δlng the same for the 2 lngs.